# Am I able to declare variable by if else/statement

Tags: java

Can you declare a variable through an if/else statement?

```
int num1;
int num2;
int num3;

if (num1 <= num2){
    num3 = (num1-num2);
}else{
    num3 = (num2-num1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, may you should try it and see what happens.  You might get a "variable might not be intialised issue", but it should work otherwise.

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself? It will be easier to find out. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can *assign* a variable in an if/else:

```
int num1 = 2;
int num2 = 3;
int num3;                // This is a declaration

if (num1 <= num2){
    num3 = (num1-num2);  // This is an assignment
}else{
    num3 = (num2-num1);  // This is an assignment
}
// We can use num3 here
```

You can also *declare* a variable in an if/else, but it won't be visible afterwards.

```
int num1 = 2;
int num2 = 3;

if (num1 <= num2){
    int num3 = (num1-num2);  // This is a declaration and assignment in one.
}else{
    int num3 = (num2-num1);  // So is this
}
// We can't use num3 here.
```

If you assign a variable in an if/else, make sure that it is guaranteed to get assigned.

```
int num1 = 2;
int num2 = 3;
int num3;

if (num1 <= num2){
    num3 = (num1-num2);  
}else if (num1 == 9) {
    num3 = (num2-num1);  
}
// We can't use num3 here because the compiler can't be sure that one of the assignments happened.
```

It is often nicer to use the conditional operator (also known as the ternary operator) rather than assigning in an if/else

```
int num3 = num1 <= num2 ? num1 - num2 : num2 - num1;
```